# group_by and sum giving me one result

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, sum

I am using `group_by` and `sum` but instead of providing group by the result I am getting only one value.

Data :

```
County     Date        GW
Moore   2018-06-18     375
Moore   2018-06-18     639
Nash    2017-12-14     358
Nash    2017-12-14     583
Wake    2017-11-07     170
Wake    2018-01-09     423
Wake    2017-04-07     342
Wake    2017-04-07     1470


NC_county <- NC_county %>% group_by(County,Date) %>% 
  summarise(Gross_Weight = sum(GW))
```

I am looking for a result like:

```
County     Date        GW
Moore   2018-06-18     1014
Nash    2017-12-14     941
Wake    2017-11-07     170
Wake    2018-01-09     423
Wake    2017-04-07     1812
```

Comment: Running your example, I got exactly what you said you wanted.  We probably need to see something like `dput(head(NC_county))`  in order to know what's going on.

Comment: Maybe you have `plyr` loaded. Try with `dplyr::summarise` instead.

Comment: Would happen have `plyr` loaded as well? It is known to interact with the `group_by` function.

Comment: structure(list(County = c("Moore", "Moore", "Nash", "Nash", "Wake", 
"Wake"), Posting_Date = structure(c(1529294400, 1529294400, 1513227600, 
1513227600, 1510030800, 1515474000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "America/New_York"), Gross_Weight = c(375, 639, 358, 
583, 170, 423)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @PaulvanOppen, RonakShah, pretty sure you guys are right.

Comment: Yes. I loaded **plyr** too.